# httpx POST request always gives "401 Unauthorized" before working fine the second attempt

Tags: timeout, http-status-code-401, digest-authentication, httpx

I'm using async with httpx in a python script to make an HTTP POST request using DigestAuth.

```
async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        try:
            r = await client.post(f"http://{str(ip)}{setConfAddr}", auth=httpx.DigestAuth(username, password), data=confPayload, timeout=10)
            logging.info(f"{str(ip)} - {r.content}")
        except httpx.RequestError as e:
            sys.exit(f"post configuration failed: {e}")
```

This was failing, giving a 401 error until I introduced the timeout,
which solved the issue I thought - but looking at the logs, I get a failure followed by success, every time:

```
2023-02-21 06:54:43,347 HTTP Request: POST http://10.0.0.17/cgi-bin/set_conf.cgi "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"
2023-02-21 06:55:05,267 HTTP Request: POST http://10.0.0.17/cgi-bin/set_conf.cgi "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
```

I added a timeout which I thought solved the issue. Apparently it just gave it more time to retry and succeed.
The result is a very slow (5-10s) delay for a successful result.

I'd like to get to the root cause of why it fails with a 401 error initially, but apparently works after a retry. I suspect it's some way in which it is doing the authorisation too quickly for the host. I'm unsure how to troubleshoot this from here.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that why it gives you `401 Unauthorized` due the authentication process wasn't completed in the meantime. So when you add a timeout or friction of delay (like you mentioned about 5-10 seconds), the request has enough time to proceed with the authentication until it's completed, thus it will give you `200 OK`

But my suggestion is, you need to check whether the request payload and the `username` or `password` that you set are correct / match with the credential.